# Netplan config with Gateway outside subnet

Tags: networking, netplan

I'm having trouble with some routing. I cannot get to 192.168.1.1 Below is the config. I have tried with onlink and without. Not sure what onlink does really. There are a few switches this machine goes through before it would hit the router. is there something i'm missing? ip route show shows that it has added the routes correctly.

Thanks!

Netplan config

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp7s0:
       addresses:
            - 192.168.0.172/24
       routes:
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
            via: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
           addresses:
               - 192.168.1.1
version: 2
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with some routing ... What is the trouble? What is it not doing you expect it to do? What are the error messages? The people who might be able to help you can not if you do not give any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have listed as your default gateway an address, `192.168.1.1`, which is not part of the configured local network, `192.168.0.172/24`.  Either the gateway for your default route should be on the 192.168.0.0 network, or you need to provide information about what the intermediate router is that lets you get to 192.168.1.1.

Comment: That makes sense. However, I don't understand how to provide information on how to route to it. How are routes set up if this was through ubuntu desktop and just connecting to the network because that works fine. Should I try to list ip tables and routes on that type of installation and copy it over?

Comment: Yes, if you have another machine on the same subnet with working networking, that's a good source for copying the correct information for your network.